# Chrome extension: how to clear address bar?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extension, address-bar

How to clear address bar (`url`) after `chrome.tabs.update`?
I use

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(taba) {
    chrome.tabs.update( { "url": "http://site.ru"} );

});
```

But I need clear address bar in Chrome, after page is loaded.

Manifest:

```
{
"web_accessible_resources": ["icons/", "icons/icon-18.png", "icons/icon-64.png", "icons/Thumbs.db"],
 "browser_action": {
"default_icon": {                 
            "19": "icons/icon-64.png",          
            "38": "icons/icon-18.png"            
          },
 "default_title": "site"}, 
 "name": "site.ru", 
 "icons": {"128": "icons/icon-64.png"}, 
 "manifest_version": 2, 
 "version": "2.0",
 "background": {
      "page": "index.html"
   },
 "permissions": [ "cookies","contextMenus","tabs","webRequest","storage",  "http://*/*", "https://*/*"], 
"description": "site.ru"
 }
```

Must be another way. **I want loading some url, when this is new tab, but in address bar field must be empty.** 
Any thinks?

Answer (score 1):

The `chrome.tabs.update` method can receive a callback function. In that callback function you can call a `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to [inject a script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-InjectDetails) into the page.

That script can use the `History API` to change the url and not trigger a reload.

If you have set permissions in the `manifest` than you can modify it.

```
   chrome.tabs.update({'url': 'http://chromium.org'}, function(tab) {

      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
           code: 'history.replaceState({}, "", " ");'
      });
    });
```

Comment: I use ` chrome.tabs.update( { "url": "http://site.ru"} ); ` . But I want to clear address bar. How can I do? I have set permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Provide console output or some debug information, please.

Comment: I corrected quotes. Site is loaded, but the address bar is not empty.

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript({
           code: 'alert("123");'
      });   this code also not working.

Comment: `history.replaceState({}, "", " ");` only replaces the path part of the URL, not the hostname.